# How to update only if my object has a certain field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongo db document like this

```
id: ObjectId(asdlkjjas_48@$#),
_user: 4593oawifjaslef,
country: { US: false, CA: false, MX: false, FR: false }
name: "kevin"
age: 28
```

I am getting a post request from the frontend with the objectId (needed to query for this document) and also a country code

So my user sends their Id and countryCode to backend, I need to update the document that matches that id, and only update the countryCode that is nested in country.

I tries something like this

```
incomingNumber = await Collection.findById(numberId) // get our document by id
const code = 'US' // get our country code
collection.updateOne({_id: incomingNumber}, {$set: { country[code]: true }}) //trying to update only the field in country(object) that matches our supplied country code(ex. 'US')
```

Comment: does this work https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

Comment: The field `country` is an _embedded document_. To work with embedded document fields use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#std-label-document-dot-notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inorder to preserve the `country` object and retain the keys that are not updated, you can either use template literals since its mongoose or use square-brackets,

```
Collection.updateOne({_id: objectId}, {$set: { ["country."+code]: true}})
```

or

```
Collection.updateOne({_id: objectId}, {$set: { `country.${code}`: true}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted the answer for a few seconds then deleted, repost your answer and i will give you credit.

The answer is to

```
Collection.updateOne({_id: incomingNumber}, {$set: { country: { [code]: true}}})
```

I basically needed an extra curly brace. This does work for me in this situation, however The country object will now look like this

```
{ US: true },
```

I would rather have

```
 { US: true, FR: false, MX: false, CA: false }
```

Comment: Hey, check the answer i have written.